# Prevent UIScrollView from stopping the scroll when a touch happen

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uikit, uiscrollview

The question is a little bit weird, but that's what I need ;)

Usually, when a UIScrollView is scrolling, if you touch the view, it stops immediately, but that's the behavior I want to change.

I've subclassed UITableView and overriden the touches* method, but while the table is scrolling no touches* events are called. As I've read in the Apple Documentation, UIScrollView (which is the parent class of UITableView) doesn't forward those events.

What I want is to detect that touch (which will stop the scroll in a ordinary scenario) but keep the UIScrollView scrolling.

So, instead stopping the scroll I want to have a method which is going to be called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:`, add a transparent view above the table view with `userInteractionEnabled` that intercepts touches. Then on `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`, remove it to restore normal interaction with the table view. Wire up touch handlers on the overlay to get callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for answering. A creative solution :). I will try it

Comment: Outstanding Solution. Appreciated

Comment: Instead of a transparent view, just set userInteractionEnabled=NO on the tableView to prevent interaction.